# Verifying a backup which I used ADB via DroidExplorer

Tags: adb, backup, droid-explorer

I have a non-rooted tablet which I did an ADB backup thru DroidExplorer.  The backup ended abruptly with no success/failure indication (which appears to be a feature of ADB).

I want to verify that the backup looks correct.  I tried using the "upack" on the file folder context menu (which I think was added by DroidExplorer?).  It asked for the password and then did nothing.

I guess there are lower level ways to unpack the file which I'll try next but my questions concerning DroidExplorer are:  Is the context menu "unpack" part of it?  Is it not working or is there a fix for it?  Also, I'd like to backup the external SD card as well...  looking at the backup file size, the backup is only doing the internal mem at most.  Is there a way to include the external SD thru DroidExplorer?  There was a choice for SD\card but I think that might only do the internal one?  And lastly, will ADB work correctly/completely on a non-rooted device?